# Microsoft Face API Python poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to run the sample of Face API from https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Python on Ubuntu 12.04 running on the virtual machine (VB). When I select the image to detect, it will send a request and will receive the results but after that:

```
sample/util.py:176: wxPyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated item EmptyImage. Use :class:`Image` instead.
wx_image = wx.EmptyImage(pil_image.width, pil_image.height)
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
python: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)`
```

I have detected the place where it stops:

```
   try:
        attributes = (
            'age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,'
            'makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise'
        )
        # the call
        res = util.CF.face.detect(path, False, False, attributes)
        faces = [model.Face(face, path) for face in res]

        # ... WON'T GET HERE ...

        self.face_list.SetItems(faces)
        util.draw_bitmap_rectangle(self.bitmap, faces)

        log_text = 'Response: Success. Detected {} face(s) in {}'.format(
            len(res), path)
        self.log.log(log_text)
        text = '{} face(s) has been detected.'.format(len(res))
        self.result.SetLabelText(text)
    except util.CF.CognitiveFaceException as exp:
        self.log.log('Response: {}. {}'.format(exp.code, exp.msg))
```

This snippet is from the sample/view/panel_detection.py

Comment: I have reproduced the error on an ubuntu VM (12.04), and I haven't had much time to dig deep but from the looks of it, the app crashes on APIs from wxPython that don't exist (i.e. when I place a breakpoint and inspect the objects I don't see the functions) so I suspect there's a problem with the version of this library. I downloaded 2.9 BTW, which is the one the sample tells us to use

Answer (score 0):

I failed to reproduce your error with the **latest version** of code on Windows 10 & macOS 10.12.5 with Python 2.7 and wxPython 3.0.2.0.

The error is not reported directly from the sample code but somewhere inside. And `wx.EmptyImage` should not be the key point of the error. So I suspect it might has something to do with the environments.

Please ensure you are using the latest version of sample code and corresponding packages. For example, 3.0.2.0 for the wxPython. Ubuntu 12.04 is too old and may suffer on outdated dependencies.

I have to admit that we have limited effort to make it back compatible so please ensure everything is up-to-date. Also feel free to update if there is any further problems.

Comment: According to the https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wxPython the latest version is 4.0.0a2 and I have this.

Comment: @Filipko wxPython 4.0+ is the next generation of wxPython which supports both Python2 and Python3. I have not tested the compatibility with this as it is still in alpha stage. So please keep using the latest 3.0+ version.

Comment: @Xuan Hu, see my comment to OP, the error is reproducible.

Comment: @Filipko so are you able to retry the sample on a different environment. Something like a real operation system (not a virtual machine) also with latest version (something like Ubuntu 16.04 LTS). If this is not applicable, please ensure your wxpython is the latest version, which should be 3.0.2.0.